# C# null memory storage

Tags: c#, memory, null

I have a class with a lot of different fields, all of them are references, like data collections.

I have to create and instantiate over a million of this type of object to be used for different things, and depends on the type of process, some of the fields remains null.

For example:

```
public class ClassBody
{
    private Dictionary<int, ClassA> classAs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassA> ClassAs { get { return classAs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassB> classBs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassB> ClassBs { get { return classBs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassC> classCs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassC> ClassCs { get { return classCs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassD> classDs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassD> ClasssDs { get { return classDs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassE> classEs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassE> ClasssEs { get { return classEs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassF> classFs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassF> ClassFs { get { return classFs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassG> classGs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassG> ClassGs { get { return classGs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassH> classHs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassH> ClassHs { get { return classHs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassI> classIs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassI> ClassIs { get { return classIs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassJ> classJs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassJ> ClassJs { get { return classJs; } }
    private Dictionary<int, ClassK> classKs;
    public Dictionary<int, ClassK> ClassKs { get { return classKs; } }
}
```

I get overly paranoid of the memory usage for the nulls... So instead I separate these fields and properties into inheritance. (Which I don't know if they take up more space than this...)

So, my very question is, without declaring --

```
classAs = new Dictionary<int, ClassA>();
```

-- where the unused fields remains null, do they take up memory space?

Comment: A million times a few bytes is just a few megs... Are you sure memory consumption is a problem ?

Comment: Every reference field consumes 4 bytes on 32-bit and 8 bytes on 64-bit. You can count yourself it that's a problem or not.

Comment: Even null still takes space?

Comment: _Even null still takes space?_ This line _private Dictionary<int, ClassA> classAs;_ is the declaration of a variable of reference type. This variable should exists somewhere in memory and takes 4/8 bytes of memory. Until you call _new_ the variable contains the null value then, when you fill it with the result of  _new Dictionary<int,ClassA>()_ it contains the reference to the memory area occupied by the Dictionary<int,ClassA> instance.